# How to perform multiple segues in TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a View Controller with an Image View at the top and a TableView at the center. The TableView has 4 sections and each section has 1 to 5 cells. It's like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T0T0.jpg 
I would like to add a segue to each cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < 3) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"London";}
        if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Tokyo";}
        if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Paris";}
    }
    [...]
    return cell;
}
```

And then I try to add a segue to each cell :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];}

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];}
    [...]
}
```

But I couldn't link the cell with the `CellIdentifier = @"Cell"` to each View Controller. It's impossible to design multiple Segue from one Cell to different View Controller on Storyboard, so how I can do it ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem : I just need to select the View Controller itself instead of the cell. Problem is solved !